# How to remove "active" on product page tab after page load

Tags: magento2, product-tab

I would like to display only title in product information tab on product page after page load. When I click on title name , need to show their particular content.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the remove `active` on product page tab after page load. You have to need update `"openedState":"active"` to `"openedState":"false"` in `details.phtml` file.

> File path:
>   magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/details.phtml

Override the `details.phtml` file to your theme and update code.

**Find:**

```
<div class="product data items" data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}'>
```

**Update to:**

```
<div class="product data items" data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"false"}}'>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working

Comment: Hi, if we click the title "active" class not added

Comment: Yes active class already removed, If you want active class then now you have to add via jquery based on onclick while click tab.

Comment: Yes i need to activate after click the title only, befor that only show title alone not a content